# Find the largest possible $\delta$ neighborhood that is proper for the given $\epsilon = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is 4.2.2 from Stephen Abbott "Understanding Analysis", I don't think I get what the problem is asking for, but this is what I *think* it is after:

For $f(x) = 5x - 6$ we are given that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} f(x)=9$.

So I am familiar with the standard $\epsilon - \delta$ proof that the limit is $9$:

Let $F: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c$ be a limit point of the domain of $A$. Given any $ \epsilon > 0,$ $\exists \delta > 0 $ s.t. whenever $0 < |x-c|< \delta$, (and $x \in A$), it follows that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

So then $0 < |x-3| < \delta$, I have $|(5x-6) - 9| < \epsilon$. This gives me $|5(x-3)|<\epsilon$, and $|x-3|< \frac{\epsilon} {5}$. This means $ 0 <|x-3|<\delta \rightarrow 0 < |x-3| < \frac{\epsilon} {5}$

So what the problem wants is... what? As the epsilon neighborhood of the limit varies by $1$, the the delta neighborhood around $x$ varies by $1/5$?

We have $V_{\epsilon}(L) = [L-1, L+1]~$ and $V_{\delta} (c) = [c- \frac{\epsilon} {5}, c+\frac{\epsilon} {5}]~$?

I'm confused but I think this is right?

Comment: Yes; $\displaystyle\delta = {\epsilon\over 5}$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman, then I have the correct $\delta$ neighborhood?

Comment: Yes, but $V_\epsilon(L) = [L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon]$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman yes, I just put $1$ there instead of $\epsilon$ because the problem said to let $\epsilon = 1$, I suppose I could have made $\delta$ numeric as well. Thank you!